# Socket connection only works once

Tags: javascript, sockets, firefox-addon

I have a server written in java listening to a port in the localhost. I'm trying to connect to it through a Firefox extension. I can send a request and receive a response but only once. Then, I don't know why it stops working: I can't even send a response.

I think that the streams close at some point but I don't know why because I set the parameters in the `pump` interface to not to close the steams when finished...

Here is my code:

```
const {components} = require("chrome");
const {NetUtil} = components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm");


var transport = null;
var outstream = null, instream = null;
var instream = components.classes["@mozilla.org/scriptableinputstream;1"]
        .createInstance(components.interfaces.nsIScriptableInputStream);
var pump = components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/input-stream-pump;1"]
        .createInstance(components.interfaces.nsIInputStreamPump);
var dataListener = null;

exports.connect = function(server, port, callback) {
    transport = components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/socket-transport-service;1"]
                          .getService(components.interfaces.nsISocketTransportService)
                      .createTransport(["udp"], 0, server, port, null);                          
    outstream = transport.openOutputStream(0, 0, 0);
    stream = transport.openInputStream(0, 0, 0);

    // Initialize
    instream.init(stream);
    pump.init(stream, -1, -1, 0, 0, false);

    dataListener = {
        receivedData: [],

        onStartRequest: function(request, context) {
            console.log("Connected to server");
        },

        onStopRequest: function(request, context, status) {
            console.log("End of request");                     
        }, 

        onDataAvailable: function(request, context, inputStream, offset, count) {
            var data = instream.read(count).replace(/\n/gm,'');         
            callback(data);   
        }
    };
    pump.asyncRead(dataListener, null); 
}

exports.send = function(data) {
    // Send data
    var outData = data + '\n';
    outstream.write(outData, outData.length);
}

exports.close = function(data) {
    // Close stream
    outstream.close();
    stream.close();
}
```

EDIT: code of java server

```
    public PluginConnection(int newPort) throws IOException {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(this.port);
}

public void send(String message) {
    if (this.clientSocket != null) {
        out.println(message);
    } else {
        System.err.println("ERROR: message could not be sent because "
                + "connection is not established.");
    }
}


public void open() {        
    try {
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();           
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: PIRServer could not open connection.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}

public String getRequest() {
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: PIRServer could not open streams.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String query = null;
    try {
        query = in.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: could not open parse query.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        out.println("-1");
    }
    return query;
}

public void close() {
    try {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();             
        }           
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();                
        }           
        if (clientSocket != null) {
            clientSocket.close();
        }
        if (serverSocket != null) {
            serverSocket.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Seems problem in server side JAVA code Can you post JAVA server code?

Comment: No, it's not a problem of the server, I try to send data to it by telnet and works fine.

Comment: have you checked by sending multiple requests? (by talnet)

Comment: nop, why would I need to do that?

Comment: I've found that, actually, `tansport` seems closed.

Comment: FWIW you should set the second parameter of `createTransport` to 1

Comment: What this parameter stands for?

Comment: @Kits89: It's the length of the array you are passing in as first parameter. Yes, it should definitely be 1 in your case. And you also might want to change the first parameter into `["tcp"]` (I guess that this is what you are actually testing with - you have TCP on the server).

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the kind of answer you're looking for but I thought I'd suggest it anyway.

Instead of using Java, you might consider node.js as the web socket server and using the MozWebSocket in Firefox. It works really well. For example, in the Firefox add-on:

```
if (typeof (MozWebSocket) != 'undefined') {
   mysocket = new MozWebSocket(SOCKET_URL);
} else if (typeof (WebSocket) != 'undefined') {
   mysocket = new WebSocket(SOCKET_URL);
} else {
   alert("Can't get socket");
}
if (mysocket === null) {
   alert("Can't get socket");
}

mysocket.onerror = function(event) {
/* error handling here */
};

mysocket.onopen = function() {
   mysocket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
   mysocket.close();
}
```

On the server side, this is all it takes from node.js:

```
var wss, http, server, wsServer, Client, fs, qs;

wss = require('node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketServer');
http = require('http');
fs = require('fs');
qs = require('querystring');

initializeServer();

wsServer.on('connect', function(connection) {
    console.log((new Date()) + " Connection accepted.");
    connection.on('message', function(message) {
        if (message && message.type === 'utf8') {
            var data = JSON.parse(message.utf8Data);
            /* parse data here */
        }
        else {
            console.log("Data is not utf8! Data = " + message);
        }
    });

    connection.on('close', function(connection) {
    console.log((new Date()) + " Client " + connection.remoteAddress + " disconnected.");
    });
});

function initializeServer() {
    server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    });
    server.listen(6969, function() {
        console.log((new Date()) + " Server is listening on port 6969");
    });

    wsServer = new wss({
        httpServer: server,
     maxReceivedMessageSize: 0x800000,
        autoAcceptConnections: true
    });
}
```